# magento multi store shows only place holder of product images on list view

Tags: multistore, product-images, list-view, list.phtml

I have setup `multi-store for magento` and `everything works fine except` the list view page, Here I get the place holder of thumbnail images and not the actual images. In between I have chosen the correct website and other admin configuration for the store specific settings. please help me, let me `know if anything else to configure.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched to default values from Choose store view and selected images respectively which cleared out this issue. Hope this should help some one.

Comment: I did not get what you say please explain more